# Getting NPE in Developing UI with Broadcast Receivers and Tabs in ActionBar

Tags: android, tabs, nullpointerexception, broadcastreceiver, android-actionbar

I am using `ActionBar Tabs` in `Android 4`. I have 5 `Broadcast receivers`, and all of them updates the part of UI. There are two Tabs in my app, both the tabs have different UI associated(that is, both tabs have different `xml` files associated with them, which will be `inflated` according to tab selection). For each Tab I am inflating a `fragment`.

Initially, I am showing only one tab. On clicking a button from the UI associated with that tab, I add another tab and I receive 5 broadcast receivers. I get broadcast receivers in any order. Now say there are following broadcast receivers: `A B C D E`

```
A, B, D and E updates the UI which is part of Tab 1.   

C updates the UI which is part of Tab 2.
```

Whenever a new tab is created, its UI gets replaced with previous tab's UI, so when, say `A and B` gets called, they update the UI which is from `Tab 1`, but when `C` is received, the UI is now replaced with `Tab2's` UI, and it updates the UI, but when `D and E` is received, they try to update the UI of `tab 1`, but since `tab 2` is now inflated, I get null pointer exception on that statement on which `D and E` tried to make change.

So please tell me, how should I update my UI according to the `broadcasters`?

**UPDATE:** Now, I am getting NPE on following: This is inside one of my receiver, here I am creating new tab and want to insert a table from the broadcast receiver.

```
ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
ActionBar.Tab bTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("B");
bFragment = new BFragment();
bTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(bFragment));
actionbar.addTab(bTab, true);

final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mdsTable); // NPE linearLayout is not getting initialized.
```

I don't understand why this is happening, since I have implemented `MyTabsListener` as:

```
class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    public Fragment fragment;

    public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Toast.makeText(StartActivity.appContext, "Reselected!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.remove(fragment);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** If I comment the receivers part(just checking if I can create tabs dynamically) and if I write the same thing outside receiver, it runs without any problem.

Please Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by:

When my `BroadCastReceivers` gets called, I save all the data that comes in `onReceive()` method, and when user moves to any Tab, it's `onCreateView()` is called, so I update the UI in this method, so no question of going directly to Tab1 from Tab2 pragrammatically, it will all be based on user's choice as to when he want to go to Tab1 from tab2, the UI will get updated and hence `NPE` is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Well, most likely you haven't associated a view with the id `mdsTable` to your current layout. It is hard to determine where the problem originates from, with only these code samples. Which layout is `mdsTable` in, and where do you inflate this layout?